# Append string to itself, 'X' number of times (Where 'x' is a variable)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML page where a user can select multiple values in a checklist. Depending on the number of items selected, that's how many times I would like to append a variable to itself, separated by commas (if that makes sense)

For example, if my string was `$string = "'$apple'"` (yes, my string is meant to be formatted this way, you'll see why) and the user selected 3 items from the checklist, my string would end up being:

"`'$apple', '$apple', '$apple'`"

When the user submits the page,  here's the PHP:

```
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
$string = 'test';

if (count($category) === 1) {
//donothing
}
else{
$category = implode(",",$category);
}
$numcat = count($category);  //count number of items in $category, save value to $numcat
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (". $category .") VALUES ('$string')");
```

For reference, if the user has selected "apple, banana, grape" from the HTML form, I want the query to essentially look like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (apple, banana, grape) VALUES ('$string', '$string', '$string')");
```

Another example, if the user has selected just "apple, grape" from the HTML form, I want it to end up looking like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (apple, grape) VALUES ('$string', '$string')");
```

The `INSERT INTO table (apple, grape)` is already solved by just doing `INSERT INTO table (". $category .")` since I have imploded it and seperated by commas, but then I also need the string to display 'X' amount of times in `VALUES`, depending on the result from `count($category)`?

How can I do this?

Comment: [str_repeat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) might be the droid you're looking for

Comment: And I won't even comment on how bad I think this approach to working with a database is

Comment: yeah deprecated mysql_ functions, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you want to take a variable and a count and make a string from it. If that is the case, will this work:

```
$value = "'x'";
$count = 3;
$a = array_fill(0, $count, $value);
$str = implode(',', $a);
```

Then, $str will contain "'x','x','x'".

You can ask why I didn't use `str_repeat`. I haven't seen a way to use a glue with that. The `implode` function lets me use , as the glue. I just needed to make it an array first.

Comment: `$str = rtrim(str_repeat($value.',', $count), ',');`

Comment: Yes. You can one-line just about anything: `$str = implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, $value));`

Comment: Was simply demonstrating how to use the `glue`

Comment: This method seems to output the correct values, but when I try to put `$str `into a mysql query, it doesn't work. There isn't any errors, but it just doesn't put anything in the database.

Comment: @RyanButterworth What is the MySQL error? Check the error logs. Print `mysql_error()`. Find the problem before you try to solve it.